# Crack the safe, find the right combination

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I recently started C# and I've got the feedback that I still repeat too much. How can I make it less repetitive?

```
namespace ExtraOefLabo
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string click = "";
    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Input

        //Proccess

        //Output
        if (click == "9382")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cracked the code!");

        }
    }

    private void btnNr1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        click+= "1";
    }

    private void btnNr2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        click +=  "2";
    }

    private void btnNr3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        click +=  "3";
    }

    private void btnNr4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        click +="4";
    }

    private void btnNr5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        click += "5";
    }

    private void btnNr6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        click += "6";
    }

    private void btnNr7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        click += "7";
    }

    private void btnNr8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        click += "8";
    }

    private void btnNr9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        click += "9";
    }

    private void BtnNr0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        click += "0";
    }

    private void btnEnd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
}
```

**XAML**

```
    <Window x:Class="ExtraOefLabo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExtraOefLabo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btnNr1" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="115,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnNr1_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNr2" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="201,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnNr2_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNr3" Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="287,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnNr3_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNr4" Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="115,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnNr4_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNr5" Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="201,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnNr5_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNr6" Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="287,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnNr6_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNr7" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="115,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnNr7_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNr8" Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="201,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnNr8_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNr9" Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="287,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnNr9_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnNr0" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="201,141,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="BtnNr0_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnEnd" Content="End" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="115,141,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnEnd_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnOk" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="287,141,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="btnOk_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**XAML:**

First I would recommend that you use the `Grid.RowDefinitions` and `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` more / better. Then all the mess with `VerticalAlignment`, `Height` etc. can be deleted. But maybe you want a specified `Height` then you still can do it:

```
<RowDefinition Height="50"/>
```

Then the XAML code looks much cleaner and e.g. like this (but it is a bit longer):

```xaml
<Window x:Class="Safe.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="1"  Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="2"  Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="3"  Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="4"  Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="5"  Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="6"  Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="7"  Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="8"  Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="9"  Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="0"  Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Content="End" Click="ButtonEndClicked"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnOk" Content="OK" Click="ButtonOkClicked"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the image below you can see that the whole grid fills the GUI and will resize if you drag the window smaller / bigger.

[image: Application GUI]

**Code behind (.cs):**

As you can see in the code above i have deleted all the event handler, because they are unnecessary and can be implemented better. This was not a recursive programming fault. It was only a little bit too much code.

Recursion is e.g. calling a function `Foo` within the function `Foo`. [The Recursion Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) may be a good first look into the chapter.

My C# code looks like this:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string click = "";

    private void ButtonOkClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.click == "9382")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cracked the code!");

        }
    }

    private void ButtonEndClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    private void ButtonNumberClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        this.click += (string)button.Content;
    }
}
```

I only have one `Eventhandler` for all the `Button`s and I am reading the number from the `Button` which was clicked. The number is saved in its `Content` Property. You can read the clicked button with the `sender` parameter of the Eventhandler Method `ButtonNumberClicked`, but you have cast the `sender` to a `Button` because otherwise you are not able to access the `Content` property.

**Hint: Casting objects**

In your special example it is very clear that the `sender` from the `ButtonNumberClicked` must be a `Button` so you can cast it safe. But if it could be also a `TextBox` then you should cast it with the `as` operator and check for `null`:

```cs
private void ButtonNumberClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        this.click += (string)button.Content;                
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks very good! I have one question though. Wich button is the ButtonNumberClicked and why is it reocurring in the xaml?

Comment: @MaartenWachters `ButtonNumberClicked` is no `Button`. It is the **Event Handler**. A `Button` implements different `Events` like the `Click` event. So when you click the `Button` the event is fired and the EventHandler Method - which is `ButtonNumberClicked` - calls the code you want to run when the `Click` event is fired

Comment: So the code is like this: You define 10 Button with content 0-9. Then you say when you click this button the code should run the `ButtonNumberClicked` method and in this method you extract the clicked button, which is button `1, 2, 3 ... 10` and get the number this button has - which is saved in the `Content` property.

Comment: Thank you for your very good explenation. I have another question though. Right now we use the event click and it checks if click is 9382. However, if I'd like to check after each button press and not on OK, do I add my if statement to ButtonNumberClicked?

Comment: @MaartenWachters yes. then you add the if to the `ButtonNumberClicked` event handler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31657/discussion-between-maarten-wachters-and-jens-horstmann).

Answer (score 4):

Building on Jens Horstmann's answer, I think we can get more compact using an `ItemsControl`.  One of the nice things about `ItemsControls` is that you can back them with *any* panel.  In this case we want a `UniformGrid`.

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        x:Name="WindowRoot">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons, ElementName=WindowRoot}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="Button" Content="{Binding}" Click="ButtonNumberClicked"/>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnOk" Content="OK" Click="ButtonOkClicked"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(Note the datatrigger to hide the button in the bottom left.)

And the code behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Buttons", typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public IEnumerable<string> Buttons
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(ButtonsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonsProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Buttons = new[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", null, "0", "End"};
    }

    private void ButtonNumberClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // See Jens Horstmann's answer (still need to account for "End"
    }

    private void ButtonOkClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // See Jens Horstmann's answer
    }
}
```

This allows us to let WPF handle the layout a bit more.  All we need to do is add buttons.  This is extensible to using letters (or any other symbol) if you wanted without having to change the XAML (except to alter the number of columns).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the XAML:

- A `UniformGrid` is a decent fit for this.
- Using routed events some more duplication can be removed.

Sample:

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <UniformGrid Columns="3" Button.Click="OnButtonClicked">
        <Button Content="1"/>
        <Button Content="2"/>
        <Button Content="3"/>
        <Button Content="4"/>
        <Button Content="5"/>
        <Button Content="6"/>
        <Button Content="7"/>
        <Button Content="8"/>
        <Button Content="9"/>
        <FrameworkElement>
            <!-- We use a this empty element as a placeholder to offset the 0-button.
                 This is a slight hack, hence this comment -->
        </FrameworkElement>
        <Button Content="0"/>
        <Button Content="End"/>
    </UniformGrid>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="OK" Click="OnButtonOkClicked" Height="50"/>
</Grid>
```

Regarding the code:

If you are learning WPF you want to learn about:

- [Bindings](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/) and why they are nice. Create viewmodels and bind to them.
- Layout using panels, here are the most useful ones (ordered): { Grid, StackPanel, Canvas, Dockpanel, WrapPanel }

I'm not saying MVVM because it tends to paralyzes beginners. When you use bindings fluently and love them good things will happen in your code.

Three reasons to not use code behind for logic like in your sample.

- A view and viewmodel is usually a nice separation of concerns.
- It is harder to test and reuse.
- Code behind for logicis not idiomatic WPF, this is an important reason when learning.